# ffprobe/ffplay/ffmpeg command for checking audio/video sync

Tags: video, ffmpeg, software-recommendation, sync

I'm working on a script that live streams 3 hours of video to several servers. Is there a command (or tool... maybe using something else like wireshark?) that I could run on each of the streams to automate a check for glaring audio/video sync issues?

If so, at least please point me to the relevant reading materials/documentation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of stream and what is your budget? There are some options for SMPTE 2022 or SMPTE 2110 at the network level. There are also options if you can insert a fingerprint. I'd also seen a product a few years back that was using facial recognition to detect mouth shapes to see if they lined up with the sounds in the audio. But all of those require a not insignificant budget.

Comment: Michael, I'm focusing on rtmp at the moment. Also, the script is using ffmpeg to launch the streams. I don't think I need anything quite that fancy. Is it possible to use ffmpeg to encode some sort of tag (perhaps at intervals of say, every 10 minutes) into the stream's audio and video that I can use as a sanity check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool is impossible. Almost.

To check sync of audio/video, you need something what appeared in both streams, what can be used as sync points. In old days used Clapperboard during film shooting. In television there was hidden timecode at border of frame, in zone of overscan which not displayed on TV

If you writing professional software, include timecodes to both streams. If not, just stream your video and audio in a single container, it enough.